# SQLAlchemy get at most N results where each category has less than M

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have three tables `A`, `B`, `C` where `A`s have `B`s and `B`s have `C`s, much like A school has classes (math, literature) and classes have students. Same named `B`s are considered the same regardless of which `A` they belong to, so do `C`s under the same `B`.

I would like to query a subset of `A`s (simple `filter`) such that I get at most `N` `B`s each having no more than `M` `C`s.

I've read about quite a few ways to get top `N` per category, but couldn't get even that (see below) to work with my `SQLite` ... query never ends.

```
    subq = sess.query(
            C,
            func.row_number().over(
                partition_by=B.name,
                order_by=C.grade).label('n')).\
        filter(~A.name.startswith('something'), B.size==2, C.grade < threshold).\
        subquery()

    q_alias = aliased(Val, subq)
    q = sess.query(q_alias).filter(subq.c.n <= M)
```

Is this even doable or should I just query for all and loop in Python until I reach `N`?

**EDIT:**

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a_objs'

    id      = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name    = Column(String(128))

    b_list = relationship('B', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic', back_populates='a')

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b_objs'

    id      = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name    = Column(String(128))

    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a_objs.id'))
    a = relationship('A', back_populates='b_list')

    c_list = relationship('C', cascade='all, delete-orphan', order_by='asc(C.grade)', back_populates='b')


class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c_objs'

    id              = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    grade           = Column(Float)
    name            = Column(String(128))

    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b_objs.id'))
    b = relationship('B', back_populates='c_list')
```

Comment: please update your question with sample schema & data

Comment: Please provide concrete models to work with, be they the A, B, and C. About the never ending query, seems like your subquery will crossjoin between the 3 tables, potentially producing an immense set of data to go through.